# (Relatively) Quickly find some divisor for a number < 10 000 000

Tags: c#, math, primes

Assume for everything that I'm talking only about natural numbers less than 10 million.

I'm looking to pre-generate a list of the Lowest Prime Divisor (LPD) for all numbers under 10 000 000. For example, LPD(14) == 2, LPD(15) == 3, and the LPD of any prime is itself.

I have pre-generated all of the primes. Accessing the nth prime is a simple array lookup. With an efficiency of: O(1)

I have pre-generated a lookup table for determining if a given number is prime. Accessing the nth prime is a simple array lookup. With an efficiency of: O(1)

Now, my naive algorithm to calculate the LPD of a given number is to loop through all the primes until one prime divides the number. But this takes a really long time. I can generate all primes under 10 million in half the time it takes to find the lowest divisor for all the numbers (using the Sieve of Atkin, which I don't understand, but implemented from pseudocode).

Is there a better algorithm for calculating the Lowest Prime Divisor?

Comment: Hopefully you are only considering primes less than `sqrt(10 000 000)`?

Comment: Good point, I really hope so too. Most of the people don't follow this practise

Comment: Yeah, well, I was first checking IsPrime(n), then checking all primes. If n is not prime, then there exists a prime less than n that divides n. I loop until I find that prime, which always happens to be less than sqrt(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually sure why you expect higher performance for much the same problem.

Rather than divide, a sieve approach would take each prime, mark all its multiples as having itself as the lowest prime factor, unless already marked.

```
int lpf[MAX] = {};
int primes[MAX_PRIME];

for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PRIME; ++i)
{
    int mult = primes[i];
    while(mult < MAX)
    {
       if (lpf[mult] == 0)
       {
            lpf[mult] = primes[i];
       }
       mult += primes[i];
    }
}
```

Any unmarked number at the end is itself prime, so this approach takes the same time as finding all the primes under `MAX`.

Comment: Sadly, this approach is about 5% slower than my original algorithm. But, good suggestion! It turns out your method can be optimized quite easily, my new code runs faster than the Sieve of Atkin for generating the primes in the first place, so I'm happy with it!

Comment: To give credit where it's due, `my method` was originally due to Eratosthenes

Comment: Here's the final adaptation!

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28207604/2028184

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `mult *= primes[i];` I think you want `mult += primes[i];`

Answer (score 0):

As adapted from @Keith's answer, the new code runs much faster (13% the old speed!):

```
    public void SieveDivisors() {
        int iNum, iPrime, i6Prime; 
        _iaFirstDivisors = new int[_iLimit];
        _iaFirstDivisors[1] = 1;
        //Start at the largest primes, then work down. This way, we never need to check if the
        // lowest prime multiple is already found, we just overwrite it
        //Also, skip any multiples of 2 or 3, because setting those is a waste of time
        for (int iPrimeIndex = _iaPrimes.Length - 1; iPrimeIndex >= 1; iPrimeIndex--) {
            iPrime = _iaPrimes[iPrimeIndex];
            i6Prime = iPrime * 6;
            for (iNum = iPrime; iNum < _iLimit; iNum += i6Prime) {
                _iaFirstDivisors[iNum] = iPrime;
            }
            for (iNum = iPrime * 5; iNum < _iLimit; iNum += i6Prime) {
                _iaFirstDivisors[iNum] = iPrime;
            }
        }
        //Then record all multiples of 2 or 3
        for (iNum = 3; iNum < _iLimit; iNum += 6) {
            _iaFirstDivisors[iNum] = 3;
        }
        for (iNum = 2; iNum < _iLimit; iNum += 2) {
            _iaFirstDivisors[iNum] = 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using the Sieve of Atkin to produce the list of primes. If you use the Sieve of Eratosthenes you automatically get your LPD array - it is simply the array you use for sieve. Instead of storing a boolean track the first prime which makes the number composite.

Here is some pseudo C code:

```
int lpd[MAX] = {};
int primes[MAX_PRIMES];
int nprimes = 0;

void sieve() {
  for (int p = 2; p*p < MAX; ++p) {
    if (lpd[p] == 0) {
      primes[nprimes++] = p;
      lpd[p] = p;
      for (int q = p*p; q < MAX; q += p) {
        if (lpd[q] == 0) { lpd[q] = p; }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the end the array `lpd[]` will contain the lowest prime divisors and `primes[]` will contain the list of prime numbers.